# Необходимо сделать обмен значений соответствующих полей двух заданных элементов массива структур

Tags: c++

Вот часть кода. Обмен номера и размера клетки происходит, но не могу понять, как сделать обмен названия :(

В коде может быть куча мусора, так как я только начал изучать язык.

Помогите пожалуйста!

```
void obmendata(zoo *M, int N) { // обмен значений соответствующих полей двух заданных элементов массива структур
    int i, j, k, tmp;
    float tmp3;
    char *tmp1;
    tmp1 = new char;
    system("cls");
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "<< Обмен значений элементов массива >>" << endl << endl;
    cout << "Введите индекс первого элемента: ";
    cin >> i;
    k = i;
    cout << "Введите индекс второго элемента: ";
    cin >> j;
    if (i == j)
    {
        cout << "Ошибка: индексы не должны совпадать!" << endl;
        cout << "Введите индекс второго элемента: " << endl;
        cin >> j;
    }
    if (i < 0 || j < 0 || i > N-1 || j > N-1)
    {
        cout << "Ошибка: индекс элемента не может быть меньше 0 или больше " << N-1 << "!" << endl;
        cout << "Введите индекс первого элемента: ";
        cin >> i;
        cout << "Введите индекс второго элемента: ";
        cin >> j;
    }
    // исходный массив
    cout << "\n<< Исходный массив >>";
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        cout << "\n";
        cout << "Номер: ";
        cout << M[i].number << endl;
        cout << "Название: ";
        cout << M[i].name << endl;
        cout << "Размер клетки: ";
        cout << M[i].size << endl;
    }
    // результирующий массив
    cout << "\n<< Результирующий массив >>" << endl;

    tmp = M[i].number;
    M[i].number = M[j].number;
    M[j].number = tmp;
    cout << "Номер: " << M[i].number << endl;;

    tmp1 = M[i].name;
    *M[i].name = *M[j].name;
    *M[j].name = *tmp1;
    cout << "Название: " << M[i].name << endl;

    tmp3 = M[i].size;
    M[i].size = M[j].size;
    M[j].size = tmp3;
    cout << "Размер клетки: " << M[i].size << endl;

    cout << "\n";
    cout << "Номер: " << M[j].number << endl;;
    cout << "Название: " << M[j].name << endl;
    cout << "Размер клетки: " << M[j].size << endl;
 }
```

Comment: А какие есть функции для **копирования** строк указанного типа?

Comment: А `tmp1` специально задана для формирования утечек памяти? Или зачем там `tmp1 = new char;`?

Comment: Уберите все звездочки из `*M[i].name = *M[j].name; *M[j].name = *tmp1;`, и уберите `tmp1 = new char;`. А вообще, обмен местами двух структур делается в одну строчку: `std::swap(M[i], M[j])`.

Comment: Определение структуры `zoo` приведите в тексте вопроса

Comment: Спасибо за подсказки, сейчас попробую

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо за помощь, `std::swap(M[i].name,M[j].name);` помогло решить мою проблему!